# How to make ng-options to choose a specific value from the dropdown list?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

I have a `ng-model` called `field.value` which is also from `ng-repeat`. when I check the `field.value` by putting inside the `<span>` element. I can check the value is `17` from which I expected the drop down goes to the `id` of `17` but it's doing nothing. How can I make the dropdown choose a value depending on `id` bound with model.

```
<div ng-if="field.name=='OrderTypeId'" class="input-group inputFill">
    <select class="form-control inputFill2" ng-model="field.value"
     ng-options="oderType.id as oderType.name for oderType in dropdown.availableOrderTypes  | orderBy:'name'  track by oderType.id">
    </select>
    <span>{{field.value}}<span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the Docs:

> ## `select as` and `track by`
>
> > Be careful when using `select as` and `track by` in the same expression.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS ng-options Directve API Reference - `select as` and `track by`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#-select-as-and-track-by-)

Comment: Without as I cannot send id to the server

Comment: After deleting track by and if I put just integer Id to ng-model such as ng-model=7, it's working but if I put field.value it's not working.